# How to record video with mic off?

Tags: microphone, video-recording, samsung-galaxy-s-10, mute

I am using a Samsung S10+. How do I record a video with no mic input ?

I have tried to put my finger over the mic, but I could still hear some background noise. I am looking to make a video in a heavy noise setting and would like to cut out the sound completely.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with a different camera app, then please try the following-

1. Install [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera)

[image: Open Camera]

2. Go to `Settings` (Top right settings icon) -> `Video settings...`
   -> Toggle `Record audio` option to disable audio.

Now you should be able to record Video without Audio. Cheers :)

Comment: @happybuddha If this answer helped, please accept this. Thanks